# Firebase Remote Config Conditions based on User Property without specifying an app

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have a project in which I have several apps (an iOS and an Android version for example).

I used to define my Remote Config conditions based directly on user properties. For example, the language selected in the app:
[image: RC condition with user prop without app]

But since a few days (weeks?), It is no longer possible, you must define the app before you can use a user property:
[image: RC condition witout app - user prop disable]

If I set the "App" property first, "User property" becomes available.
But a condition can target only one app, so I will have to make one condition per application which becomes very painful.

Existing conditions still seem to work, but impossible to edit them with other user properties.

Did I miss something?
**Is there a way to make "multi application" conditions based on user properties?**

Comment: facing the same issue, did you find any solution?